# Constrain node position

Tags: cytoscape.js

My main problem is to limit the size of the layout, so that the nodes can't be placed outside the borders. The documentation says that there's a boundingBox property that can be set for a layout object, but here's the problem - no matter what values I set for the boundingBox I still can place the nodes across the pan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put the node within the bounds you want after `free` events.

Layouts are responsible only for setting node positions.  They do not create ongoing constraints.  You can create whatever constraints you want with your own code.